# Can measurable spaces be generalized via Topologic spaces?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I'm having some confussions about the differences between $\sigma$-algebras and topologies over sets.
My main confussion is about wether or not one can be generalized by the other one. The definitions are evidently similar:

### Definition 1:

A $\sigma$-algebra is a set $\Sigma\subseteq P(X)$, where $P(X)$ is the power set of a given set $X$ such that, for every $A_i\in\Sigma$, the following axioms hold:

1. $X\in\Sigma$
2. $A^\prime_i\in\Sigma$
3. $\left(\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i\right)\in\Sigma$

Also, it can be inferred from the axioms that $\Sigma$ is closed under countable (finite) intersections, and that $\emptyset\in\Sigma$ (wikipedia).

We also have that

### Definition 2

A topology over a set $X$ is a class $\Sigma$ of subsets of $X$ that satisfies, for every $A_i,A_j\in\Sigma$:

1. $A_i\cup A_j\in\Sigma$
2. $A_i\cap A_j\in\Sigma$

Also, by definition, $\emptyset,X\in\Sigma$.

Given these two definitions, i claim:

*$U$ is closed for $U\in T\Leftrightarrow T$ is a measurable space*

Where $T$ is a topological space.

*Proof:*
Let $T=(X,\Sigma)$ be a topological space, such that all open subsets $U\in T$ are closed sets. Since $U$ is open and closed (clopen), then $U^\prime$ is also clopen, so $U^\prime\in T$. By definition, $X\in T$ and $T$ is closed under arbitrary unions, so $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and the space $T$ is measurable.

To prove the other way of the implication, we start with measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. We define an open subset $U$ to be open iff $U\in\Sigma$.
By definition, $U^\prime\in\Sigma$, so $U^\prime$ is open. Suppose $A,B\in\Sigma$ are open. $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions and intersections, so $A\cap B\in \Sigma$ and $A\cup B\in\Sigma$ are open. Finally, every $U^\prime,A\cup B,A\cap B\in\Sigma$ is open so $\Sigma$ is a topology, and the space $T=(X,\Sigma)$ is a topological space where $U\in T$ is closed. $\square$

This proof seems ok, and appears to correctly generalize measurables spaces in terms of topological ones. Is this proof ok?

Comment: $\sigma$-algebras have the property of being closed by complementation, which topologies don't have. On the the other hand, topologies have the property of being closed under union of arbitrary subfamilies, which $\sigma$-algebras do not have and which your "Definition 2" omits.

Comment: In the proof i showed a topology that is closed under complementation. You might be right about the union of arbitrary families, though. I however, think that iff those families are countable, their union will still be countable, validating the proof... But are they? Countable?

Comment: measure spaces and topological spaces have different properties. There are strong links - it is common to consider topological measure spaces i.e. Borel sigma algebras - but neither generalises the other. Topologies are **not** closed under complementation

Comment: But then, how is the proof flawed? If two things have different properties they needn't to be different. Natural and real numbers have different properties, but they are both complex. Maybe there is something wrong with the axioms/definitions? I did posted them on memory.

Comment: Btw, finite topologies are closed under comolementation.

Comment: @SimónFlavioIbañez Btw, no, they are not.

Comment: "How is the proof flawed?" It's flawed because you did not show that the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ is closed under arbitrary unions. This corresponds, as you've already been told, to the fact that your Definition 2 is incorrect - it omits closure under arbitrary unions.  A counterexample is given by the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, which is not a topology.

Comment: discrete topologies (whether finite or not) are closed under complementation. but finite topologies need not be discrete and need not be closed under complementation. Consider the Sierpinski space with two points, one of which is closed.

Comment: Yes, the discrete topology is obviously closed under complementation. But not every topology on a finite set is discrete. Consider, for example, the [Sierpinski space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpiński_space).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. So it appears that it is not ageneralization, after all.

Comment: @SimónFlavioIbañez It is true that a set of set is a topology and a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if it is a topology where all open sets are closed. This property may be situationally true, and apparently the topologies that have it are called "locally indiscrete".

Comment: *Natural and real numbers have different properties, but they are both complex.* --- Given a set $X,$ a topology on $X$ (defined either as a collection of *open* sets or as a collection of *closed* sets) and a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ are both [lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) on ${\mathcal P}(X)$ (power set of $X$ -- set of all subsets of $X).$ By the way, this is not to be confused with the fact that it's also the case **(continued)**

Comment: that on ${\mathcal P}({\mathcal P}(X))$ [all topologies on $X$ is itself a lattice](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-5/issue-2/The-lattice-of-topologies-A-survey-equations/10.1216/RMJ-1975-5-2-177.full) and [all $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ is itself a lattice](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4295761/13130), which incidentally are studied together in [*On the lattice of* $\sigma$-*algebras*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/on-the-lattice-of-algebras/DE5E1F44CC8FF1AD6B9DE79A02F659A0) by Rayburn (1969).